# How to set equal space between number and title in table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, article

I want to make a style with TOC, that has equal space between number and title.

I tried to make it with `titlesec`, but something going wrong and a I have extra TOC entries with default style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection~~#1}{1em}{}[
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thesection~#1}]

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents 

\section{Fisrt}
\setcounter{section}{98999}
\section{section}


\end{document}
```

How can I  set equal space between number and title in table of contents in the best way?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package for adjusting the ToC and friends. I hope this gives you what you are after.

```
% tocnumprob.tex  SE 575762

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{comment}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection~~#1}{1em}{}[
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thesection~#1}]
\end{comment}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3.5em}  % change this to suit

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents 

\section{Fisrt}
\setcounter{section}{98999}
\section{section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I wasn't clear about what you wanted, and I'm still not sure. The above put all section numbers into a fixed width box, which is the normal LeTeX style. The following just prints the section numbers followed by a space of some length. Perhaps this is what you are after.

```
% tocnumprob.tex rev 2 SE 575762 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{comment}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection~~#1}{1em}{}[
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thesection~#1}]
\end{comment}

\usepackage{tocloft}
%\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3.5em}  % change this to suit more space for section numbers
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%    % don't put section numbers in a box
  {\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum\hfil}\@cftasnumb}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{\hspace{1em}} % change this to suit space after section number
\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents 

\section{Fisrt}
\setcounter{section}{98999}
\section{section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, but I meant, that space is counting from number, not from toc right border

Answer (score 2):

Since you load  `titlesec`, you can as well do that with `titletoc` and its `\titlecontents` and `\contentslabel` commands:  you just have to save the necessary space for long section numbers and load the package with the `rightlabels` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[rightlabels]{titletoc} %
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\toclabelwd}
\settowidth{\toclabelwd}{99999}
\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{#1}%
\titlecontents{section}
     [\toclabelwd] % i
     {\medskip}
     {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\toclabelwd}\enspace}
     {}
     {\hfill\contentspage}%]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{A First Section}
\lipsum[1-6]
\setcounter{section}{98999}
\section{Another Section}
\lipsum[7-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]